# There is no object in this control

Tags: ms-access, ms-office

At work, we often create access applications to perform imports from certain files to the database. 
We always create those mde files in access 2003. 
Normally, people who run these applications have a full office (with access) installed and are able to run the .mde files.

For a new application we have a user that has an office 2010 installed, without access. 
So we installed an access runtime version on their PC's so they would be able to open and use our mde file. Although we keep getting the "there is no object in this control" when we open the .mde file with the access RT version.

Anyone has an idea what is causing this issue ?

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We fixed it by removing a Progress bar from the application. The libraries were not included in the runtime version neither by default in Windows. After removing it, the application ran perfectly fine on the RT editions of Access.

Answer (score 0):

When you build a runtime package you have to make sure all dll and other references are included so they get installed on the users machine.  I would guess you are missing one of them.  Do you know where to view references?  If not make sure to open the VBE and look under tools/references.  Remove any that aren't used.  Then make sure any that are used are in your runtime package.

Comment: How can i check if they are used in my runtime package?

Comment: That is the trouble with runtime, you can't check from the problem machine what the error is.  You can only check all the references from the developer machine and make sure they are included.  I used to manage 100+ machines with Access databases I deployed.  I was much happier when we started installing full Access on all the machines.  I would recommend that.  It will make any other debugging much easier as well.

Comment: In my experience Access can be very quirky and sometimes what works on 99 machines won't work on one.  The only good way to find out what the issue is is to have the full VBE and query tools etc.